# IIS 502.5 error when publishing aspnetcore web api in sub-folder of root

Tags: iis, azure-devops, asp.net-core-webapi, octopus-deploy

I have two applications totally independent as:

1. Angular 6 app
2. AspNetCore Web Api

I tried publishing AspNetCore web app in my www.xxx.com(`D:ABCPub\wwwroot`) root of IIS without any problem and my web api works like a charm, but the issue is when I tried to put my published files in www.xxx.com/mywebapi(`D:ABCPub\wwwroot\mywebapi`) it gives me error as below:
[image]
Given that currently my root`D:ABCPub\wwwroot` is totally empty except the folder `mywebapi` which contains all the published files.

Below is my web.config(`D:ABCPub\wwwroot\mywebapi\webconfig`) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyProject.Service.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: AD1729B0-5EEA-46C7-B21F-349377540A21-->
```

I think I am doing some silly mistake here, but not able to get it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For `www.xxx.com/mywebapi` in IIS, `mywebapi` should be an application under `www.xxx.com` website with application pool configured to run with `No Managed Code` as `.NET CLR version`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood thanks for your reply, but I have already done that, but no luck.

Comment: One more thing I noticed today, when I emptied the `mywebapi` folder and just inserted a blank `index.html` file, it was accessible via `www.xxx.com/mywebapi`, so maybe there is a problem in my aspnetcore web api project?

Comment: Check the server event viewer for the exception logs

Comment: Can you fix your problem ? i have same !

Answer (score 0):

The AspNetCoreModule is configured via the web.config file found in the application's root, which points a the startup command (dotnet) and argument (your application's main dll) which are used to launch the .NET Core application. The configuration in the web.config file points the module at your application's root folder and the startup DLL that needs to be launched.See [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS).

Try to add arguments=".\ABCPub.dll" in the web.config like below

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ABCPub.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

Comment: Following your process I am getting this error
`A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'D:\ABCPub\wwwroot\mywebapi\'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the D:\ABCPub\wwwroot\mywebapi\MyProject.Service.runtimeconfig.json file specifying the appropriate framework.`

Comment: You may use a wrong dll.The dll file should be the file included in mywebapi folder.If you publish your project in D:\ABCPub\wwwroot\mywebapi\, I think it should be there.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, even if you are right, but my question is that `www.xxx.com/mywebapi` should be independent on root`(D:\ABCPub\wwwroot)` folder, because in this root folder I will have my angular app `index.html` page